# Web Crawler with Ajax/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler

I have tried to use HtmlUnit to implement a crawler which can obtain the results generated by executing the Ajax request and javascript's execution.However, HtmlUnit is not so powerful to meet my demand because it can't obtain all the rendered DOM element generated by executing JavaScript or AJax. And then I aslo tried to use pywebkitgtk and pyQtwebkit, it did generated some dynamic DOM element.But they don't work stably, and I have no idea to tackle it.  It seems that someone aslo mentioned using the selenium.Can anybody give me some suggestions to implement a Ajax Crawler?   Many thanks!

Comment: Generally my understanding is you need JavaScript runtime to do what a real browser does like Ajax requests and async handler. I vote for the [selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) way because it allows to operate real browser in scripting way so that it covers the web crawler scenario perfectly plus additional feature like screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay,I will try to use the selenium. Hope it will work! :D

Answer (score 1):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) might be a good solution to your problem. And you can also make use of some crawler api, e.g. [Unicrawler](http://bestmike007.com/unicrawler/), to simplify this. Hope it works.